# Confusion_matrix ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous-multioutput targets

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

can anyone fix undersampling confusion matrix error from the line:
undersample_cm = confusion_matrix(original_ytest, undersample_fraud_predictions)
I think the problem is from the import or ***original_ytest*** and ***undersample_fraud_predictions***

```
undersample_cm = confusion_matrix(original_ytest, undersample_fraud_predictions)
actual_cm = confusion_matrix(original_ytest, original_ytest)
labels = ['No Fraud', 'Fraud']
```

[The picture of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZIIJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

confusion_matrix works with two arrays of same size, same type of data.

```
y_true = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

I guess there is a continuous variable in any of your arrays. For this, if you run the actual_cm line first, you can see which array is the problem. One of your arrays, namely original_ytest, contains integer values ​​as it should, but you're probably getting an error because it contains continuous values ​​in the undersample_fraud_predictions array.

```
original_ytest = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
undersample_fraud_predictions = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5]
confusion_matrix(original_ytest , undersample_fraud_predictions )
```

When you run the code I want to explain above, the error you get will be the same (Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets).